# VB.NET - Ribbon Shows Black Area

Tags: vb.net, ribbon, aero

I need help with my vb.net program. I've added a ribbon bar to the top of my main form using the [DotNetBar](https://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) and the problem is that it shows a black rectangle area instead of the default blue color. This only happens when I am using Windows 7 aero and is not maximized.

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but it looks like DotNetBar is meant to be used without the standard Form chrome. Try setting your form's border style to `None`.

Also, make sure you're following the directions and using a DotNetBar form control:
http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=703

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. I forgot to change the inherits from office 2007 form to office 2007 ribbon form on the main designer.